# How to have reflector load a different framework on load

Tags: c#, .net, reflector

When you first start .NET Reflector, it'll ask you what framework's base assemblies it should load. I often switch from framework to framework and wondered how I could have it popup that question each time (other than reinstalling). Or do I have to manually create lists for each

I can't seem to find it anywhere in the menu or under options.

EDIT: in case you wonder what I mean or haven't had a "first use" in a while, these are the choices I'm referring to, image [referred to from here](http://www.myviewstate.net/blog/post/2009/05/15/Weekly-Tool-Tip-Introducing-NET-Reflector.aspx) (nowadays includes .NET Framework 4.0, of course):

http://www.myviewstate.net/blog/image.axd?picture=select_framework_version.png

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reflector shows that list when it starts with no assemblies already loaded.

If you delete all the assemblies from the main view in Reflector and then close it down, it will pop up with the "Start Default Assembly List" dialog again when you next start it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use 'Open List' menu item from the File menu to create lists and switch between them. When you create a new list and click select it will display the list which is shown when you first run the application.

Comment: Thanks, but see *"Or do I have to manually create lists for each"*, I hoped to avoid this. It doesn't list the lists that you see on first run.

Comment: @Abel, when you create a new list and click select it will display that list.

Comment: Yes, of course. Maybe I don't make myself very clear. It's the *first use* choice I'm looking for. See http://www.myviewstate.net/blog/image.axd?picture=select_framework_version.png (from this article: http://www.myviewstate.net/blog/post/2009/05/15/Weekly-Tool-Tip-Introducing-NET-Reflector.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain what you are asking for, but it sounds like you would like a menu choice that would allow you to change the base framework version being used as well as the existing assemblies in the tree ... is that right?

I could add this to my powercommands addin, it would do something like this:

1. you have all the assemblies loaded in your tree doing your normal reflector thing
2. you decide, hey I want to change the framework to use version x
3. you click tools menu -> change framework
4. a dialog pops up that asks you which to choose (will look like the reflector one but will have to be a custom one)
5. you choose the framework version
6. the assembly tree then gets any of the default framework assemblies you had in the tree, removed and repopulated with the new framework version assemblies AND the other assemblies you had in the tree as well

Is that the sort of functionality you are looking for?

Comment: That is *exactly* the type of functionality I am looking for! If you could add that functionality, that would be great!

Comment: That would be a great addition!

Comment: Sorry guys, been REALLY busy lately - I should get to this early September (2 weeks).

Comment: Sorry, been super busy. i'll try and work on it this weekend.